# How do I determine Offset of this particular wheel?

Tags: tires, wheels

Am buying some new winter wheels, downsizing from 19" to 17". BMW X1 E84.
Specs call for: 7.5jX17 ET34

I have found an excellent set online, private sale, the gentleman is super helpful, but can't seem to find the offset (ET) specified anywhere on the wheels.

The information he can find and gave me is:
7 1/2 jx-17seh2
En-ac Aisi7
K8
6761929-14
IS40

Question: is it possible to find the offset from the above information?  e.g by cross referencing one of those numbers on a part's website?

And is it possible that the offset is indeed not stamped into these wheels - or has he just somehow missed it and needs to look again?

UPDATE: I was looking wheels for `ETxx` (offset) stamped on the wheels.  It turns out that some wheels use `ISxx` instead of `ETxx` - so the `IS40` stamped on these wheels means they have a +40mm offset....live and learn!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some research over at https://www.hubcaphaven.com/p/8892/aly59444-bmw-x5-wheel-silver-painted-36116761929.html show that these wheels (based on the partnumber 6761929) have an offset of 40mm. Given that '40' appears in the information given, I'd be pretty solid with that number.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks.  Additionally for any one else that stumbles across this: The wheels are stamped with "IS40", which I now know is the same as "ET40".  I.e wheels may specific the offset using either "ET" or "IS" codes...